# angular typescript declare generic with empty object

Tags: angular

I am trying to declare following variable in angular 12

```
private subject = new BehaviorSubject<ApiResponse>({});
```

I get error

```
Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ApiResponse'
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ApiResponse'
```

The class ApiResponse has following properties

```
export interface ApiResponse {
  success: boolean
  message: string
  exception: any
  totalRowCount: number
}
```

If I declare each property explicitly, it works without error
Is there a way to declare an empty object without declaring each property explicitly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `?` for optional properties

```
export interface ApiResponse {
  success?: boolean;
  message?: string;
  exception?: any;
  totalRowCount?: number;
}
```

Comment: is there any setting in tsconfig that can be used to allow empty objects ?

Comment: No need to change any config @SudhirJangam

Answer (score 0):

use `ReplaySubject` instead of `BehaviorSubject`. in most of the cases you don't want to handle the empty object, while the response didn't come yet